# Delete post meta front end

Tags: front-end, php

I have a simple foreach loop and am putting together a timeline app. I'm using gravity forms to create / edit posts on the front end and am looking for a solution for a button or trigger that can delete a posts custom field (key & value) on click.

Pretty broad but along the lines of:

- target this post in foreach
- find meta key 'key'
- delete meta key 'key' and its value on click

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for guidance on how to do this, I created another custom field called event_status and by using the save_post action in wordpress set a condition that once this changes to then the run delete_post_meta action as follows:

```
function event_status_is_updated($post_id){
  if(get_post_meta($post_id,'event_status',true)=='not_complete'){
    delete_post_meta($post_id,'date_dun');
  }
 }
add_action('save_post_event','event_status_is_updated');
```